# Algorithm for bending image

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, 3d, python-imaging-library

Here's the result I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

My algorith currently is:

1. This canvas photo is transparent where the design goes.
2. I resize the design so it's just a little bigger than the size of canvas photo
3. I paste canvas photo onto design

It works okay but it I need image to bend in the corners. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Here's my current algorithm code written in python with PIL:

```
def merge_case_image(case_path, design_path, save_path):
    case = Image.open(case_path)  # cas template

    design = Image.open(design_path)  # design
    design.thumbnail(case.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)  # resize design
    design_w, design_h = design.size

    bg_white = Image.new('RGBA', case.size, (255, 255, 255, 255))  # white background
    bg_w, bg_h = bg_white.size

    offset = ((bg_w - design_w) / 2, (bg_h - design_h) / 2)

    if design.mode == "RGBA":
        bg_white.paste(design, offset, design)
    elif design.mode == "RGB":
        resizeImageMask = Image.new("L", design.size)
        resizedImagePixels = design.load()
        width, height = design.size
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                cpixel = resizedImagePixels[x, y]
                if ((cpixel[0] == 255) and (cpixel[1] == 255) and (cpixel[2] == 255)):
                    resizeImageMask.putpixel((x, y), 0)
                else:
                    resizeImageMask.putpixel((x, y), 255)

        bg_white.paste(design, offset, resizeImageMask)

    bg_white.paste(case, (0, 0, bg_w, bg_h), case)

    bg_white.save(save_path, "PNG")
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please show your current output. If you want to simulate the graphics being folded on the sides, you will need to apply a shear transform to parts of the image. (If available, a perspective warping is even better.)

Comment: Would say it is a typical uv-Texturecoordinate problem. The "trick" is to distribute the u and v coordinates intelligent on your 3d picture frame. Just read a bit about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping.